# Can't open categories or switch between categories - Magento CE 1.9.1.1

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ajax

I've switched hosting and have everything in the admin panel working fine except Catalog > Categories. When I try to open them or switch to /click on any other category within the list - I just get the below error and nothing changes.

`http://domain.tld/index.php/adminzone/catalog_category/edit/key/<key>/id/58/?isAjax=true 403 (Forbidden)`

Any thoughts? Not even sure where to look for details - I searched the web but mostly found details on Nginx servers or Magento CE 1.7 update. This is a more recent version and it is on Apache.

Comment: Enable apache debug logging - There may be a clue in the results.